Path analysis indirect correlation highly correlated to direct one. Is this expected?
Assume B has a direct effect on A and C has a direct on A as well. Here γ, α and β are the corresponding correlations. β is an indirect "artificial" correlation and γ*α is "true" correlation.
The correlations I'm computing are raw correlations.
Is it expected that γ*α is highly correlated to β?

Now for this other case, is the indirect path γθα expected to be correlated to the direct path β?
In general I'm unsure on how to set the equations in this path diagram.
And whether these "high" correlations I'm obtaining have a meaning, or it is just something expected from the way I set these diagrams.


There's a lot of unconventional language here, which makes it hard to give a good answer. Is alpha a correlation or a regression? It looks like a regression. What's an "artificial" and "true" correlation? Why should y * alpha mean anything?

y * theta * alpha is not an indirect path.

I agree that the distinction between "artificial" and "true" correlation seems strange and warrants further discussion if a better answer is desired.

alpha,beta,theta are all correlations.

I meant y * theta * alpha is an indirect path between B and C.

Obviously your first path analysis diagram could possibly depicts a collider case where B and C have no marginal dependence at all, therefore your "true" raw correlation $\gamma \alpha$ may not correlate to the "artificial" raw correlation $\beta$ in any linear sense.
Same goes for your second path diagram, regardless from your specific observational data you might be obtaining high correlations, it's not always expected.
